# Jquery dynamically append option to a selectlist and then make the new option selected

Tags: jquery, selectlist

I am dynamically adding an option to a selectList and trying to make it the selected item but the following code does not seem to make the option selected. It does ad the option, however.

```
$("#LicenseId").append(data).prop("selected", true);
```

What am I doing wrong, please?

Comment: What exactly is `data`, and what is `#LicenseId` ?

Comment: LicenseId is the Id of the selectlist and data is the html code of the option being added. The first part works, setting the new option as selected is not working. Thanks.

Comment: Right now you're setting the select element to selected, and that wont work, show us exactly what `data` is ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to unselect the currently selected option first:

```
var d = $('<div />').append(data).find('option').prop('selected', true);

$("#LicenseId").find('option').removeProp('selected').end().append(d);
```

Answer (score 1):

Aside from using prop, you could also try the attr method.

```
$("#LicenseId").append(data).attr("selected", "selected");
```